# Is there a way to keep scrollbar displaying when the component is updating?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I developed a platform to show different shop data as jpg shows.
Is it possible to update the Dashboard with the scrollbar keeping displaying on the right hand side like facebook's loading does?

Currently, when the dashboard updates, no scrollbar shows at all.

[image]

Comment: Updating alone does not effect scrollbar. It's impossible. There's something else happening when your loading begins that hides scrollbar.

Comment: This seems more like a CSS question, you could add `overflow-y: scroll` to the body via a class while loading?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a placeholder of a fixed or min height which the component is loading.
This could be done easily with `css` only bij giving the wrapper of the component a `min-height` (e.g. `min-height: 500px`) . Or if you are fetching data from the server you can set a loading boolean when the data is fetching and swap out the component for a loading component which has the fixed height

Answer (score 0):

After checking my control flow carefully, I found that a waiting circle is always loaded before any page update:

```
export async function prepareAndRedirect(w,p){
...
    dispatch(redirectTo('WAITING_ROTATING_CIRCLE'));
    //operations
}
```

So, when the page shows the CircularProgress, no scrollbar shows because of CircularProgress' height.

I change the code to be

```
//PAGE_DASHBOARD needs to always show its scrollbar.
if(p!='PAGE_DASHBOARD') dispatch(redirectTo('WAITING_ROTATING_CIRCLE'));
```

So when the target page loads in the facebook's update way, the scrollbar stays.
About this, jank is right: if the page content updates without interruption, its scrollbar stays.

Thanks a lot for you guys' help.